# Такую ошибку даже я(,) не думаю, чтобы сделал

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Такую ошибку даже я(,) не думаю, чтобы сделал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая по [3-му пункту](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137) не нужна:

*Такую ошибку даже я не думаю, чтобы сделал*.

Главная часть *не думаю* внутри изъяснительного придаточного.

Ср.:

*Не думаю, чтобы такую ошибку даже я сделал*.

Или:

*Даже я не думаю, чтобы такую ошибку сделал*.

В этом случае главная часть *даже я не думаю* внутри изъяснительного придаточного. Но в обоих случаях запятая не нужна.

Comment: Интересно, сколько еще вопросов будет задано по  3-му пункту, на которые вы будете отвечать. Неиссякаемый источник вдохновения и еще один образец спам-вопроса.  Спамики многолики...